# Android Things SPI Burst Length NXP i.MX7D

Tags: spi, android-things

I'm using the NXP i.MX7D with Android Things to read images from a camera via SPI. The image is broken down into packets of 244 bytes but it appears that the Android Things drivers only handle bursts of 64 bytes before the CS and CLK are deasserted for a period of time. The problem is that this invalidates the packet.

To change this behavior, I can toggle the BURST_LENGTH field in the ECSPI_CONREG register. I do not think I have the ability to change a register through Android Things but I think I can using the NDK and a C program. If I make this change will the Android Things SPI driver work as is or will I have to craft my own in C?

Comment: As an alternative, can you do bit-banging to read the 244 bytes?

Comment: Yeah but I am trying to stick to the Android Things utilities. It appears that I cannot write to the register (Linux got me!)

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to modify the underlying implementation of the SPI driver.

Comment: That's what I am figuring. It would be nice if this platform could offer the ability to tweak registers if need be for certain peripheral communication for specialized hardware. I really think this platform is powerful but I think for my application it will not work.

Comment: We have a feature request filed to increase the SPI buffer size: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71010856
Feel free to track that request for updates, or file a new issue if that one does not exactly match your issue.